# how to make an ImageView visible on swiping a listview row?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, visibility, swipe

I have used `<com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView>` to generate a ListView. I am using the following xml to get the items in my `SimpleAdapter`

```
custom_row.xml

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back"
        style="@style/MyListBackContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="back" 
       >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/example_imagess"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#8250a5"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_status" />




    </LinearLayout>
     <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/front"

     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"


     android:tag="front" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/example_itemname"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to make the ImageView `ii` visible when the listview row is swiped to the left and hide the same imageview ii when the listview row is swiped to the right.
myfriends extends Fragment class

```
  ListAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val,R.layout.custom_row,new String[]{"fbname"},new int[]{R.id.example_itemname}){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
             final ImageView ii=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.example_imagess);
            // final View orange=(View)v.findViewById(R.id.orangeview);
             swipy.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener(){

                @Override
                public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onOpened(position, toRight);
                    //swipy.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onClickFrontView(position);

                    swipy.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.swipy_list_color));

                }

                @Override
                public int onChangeSwipeMode(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onchangeSwipeMode",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    swipy.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.swipy_list_color));
                    ii.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);

                    return super.onChangeSwipeMode(position);
                }
```

my swipelistview is as follows:

```
       <com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        android:id="@+id/example_swipe_lv_list"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"

        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/choice_selected"
        swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/choice_unselected"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"

        swipe:swipeMode="both"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the x like this.

You shouldn't set the swipeListViewListener in the adapter, try setting it in your activity or fragment instead. The way your doing it right now, in your adapters getView(), is setting a new swipeListViewListener to your listView for each row in your list.

```
// In your activity/fragment
swipeListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMove(int position, float x) {
            super.onMove(position, x);
            int index = position - swipeListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View currentRow = swipeListView.getChildAt(index);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) currentRow.findViewById(IMAGE_ID);

            if (x < 0) {
                // RIGHT, hide your imageView
                imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                // LEFT, show your imageView
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }                   
        }
    });
```

Comment: The ImageView is Visible for the if(x<0) condition but it is not setting to invisible. can u suggest something please?